# Intersection of sets is indeed a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

My question is pretty straight forward - how do I use ZF axioms to prove that if $\{A\}_{i\in\Bbb{N}}$ is a family of sets, then $\bigcap_{i}A_i$ is a set?

I feel like I should be using the axiom of union and the axiom of separation, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: @Gae.S. Intersection.

Comment: It's just that obviously $\bigcap_i A_i$ is contained in $\bigcup_i A_i$ so by the axiom of separation and axiom of union I can get the desired result?

Comment: The intersection of an empty family of sets is not well-defined in ZF. The intersection of a non-empty family of sets is given to you by the axiom of separation (it is contained in $A_{i_0}$ for any $i_0$ in the index set).

Comment: @RobArthan so how do I treat the case where all sets are empty?

Comment: @GBA The case where all the $A_i$-s are empty is not a problem. It's the case where $I=\emptyset$ that results in a proper class.

Comment: If all the $A_i$ are empty and there is at least one $A_i$, then the intersection is empty. The only problematic case is $\bigcap_{i \in \emptyset} A_i$, for which the membership condition would be vacuously true, so that $\bigcap_{i \in \emptyset} A_i$ would have to have every set as a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise, we must prove the following statement:

For all non-empty $I$, for all index families $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$, there exists a unique set $S$ such that for all $x$, $x \in S \iff \forall i, x \in A_i$.

To prove this, suppose we such an $I$ and a family $A$. Then let $j$ be an element of $I$. Then by the axiom of separation, there exists $S$ such that for all $x$, $x \in S \iff x \in A_j \land \forall i \in I, x \in A_i$. We then immediately see that for all $x$, $x \in S \iff \forall i \in I, x \in A_i$. Thus, we have shown existence.

For uniqueness, we note that if we have two such sets $S$ and $S'$, then for all $x$, $x \in S \iff (\forall i \in I, x \in A_i) \iff x \in S'$ and hence $S = S'$ by the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: Do you require the Axiom of Choice to choose an element j of I?

Comment: @M_N1 No. We are just using the properties of an existential quantifier - specifically, existential elimination (also known as existential instantiation).

Answer (score 2):

They way I learned it (I believe this is how Halmos gives it, but he isn’t writing a fully formal presentation of $\mathsf{ZF}$), the Axiom of Union guarantees the existence of the unary union. We know that for all $X$ there exists $A$ such that
$$\forall z\Bigl(\bigl(\exists y (y\in X\wedge z\in y)\bigr)\longrightarrow z\in A\Bigr).$$
and then with Separation we can define
$$\bigcup X = \{z\mid \exists y(y\in X\wedge z\in y)\}.$$
Once we have defined the (unary) union, we define the unary intersection by
$$\bigcap X = \left\{z\in \bigcup X\Bigm| \forall y (y\in X\longrightarrow z\in y)\right\}$$
which is a set by the Axiom of Separation.

Note that with this definition, you would get that the empty intersection is empty; some people don’t like that (and there are good reasons for avoiding it, and good reasons for not minding or even wishing that). In any case, you can use the latter definition to conclude that $\bigcap X$ is a set in $\mathsf{ZF}$ for any particular nonempty $X$.